# Laravel Livewire is not defined

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Si al igual que yo probaste de todo lo que había en los foros y nada te sirvió, permíteme ayudarte.
Estaba usando livewire 2.x con laravel 8.x(sin jetstream) y las funciones de livewire terminaban con un 404 not found al livewire.js
Nota: Ya había publicado los assets y modificado el asset_url

SOLUCIÓN
Al probar en Apache en Laragon, xampp y el server incluido en Artisan me di cuenta que el error no es el servidor.
El asset_url en config/livewire.php debes apuntarlo de la siguiente manera:
"http://localhost:puerto/proyecto/public"

Pero el secreto está en también configurar con la misma ip el archivo env en la parte de APP_URL:
http://localhost:puerto

Las partes de localhost deben ser sustituidas por la IP a utilizar como fija

De esta forma a mi me funcionó sin problemas y los puedes testear desde otros dispositivos si estuvieses en la misma LAN, si lo vas a montar en un hosting hacer los ajustes para adaptarlo a tu dominio.

Al menos a mi el error me lo estaban dando los host virtuales que generaba laragon ya que mi APP_URL en el archivo env no lo había apuntado correctamente, se me quedaba el .test y jamás encontraba el archivo livewire.js

Comment: Te comento que la solución no va en la pregunta, por favor publicala donde corresponde que es la zona de respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Después de haber visto decenas de foros, este método fue el único que me sirvió.

Sólo deben colocar la misma url en ambos archivos.

en config/livewire.php, asset_url = 'https://tudominio',
en el .env APP_URL = 'https://tudominio'